# MySqlCommand Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to update calorie_tracker table after burned value is calculated.Until cmd2 command it works.But while trying to cmd2 gives an error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.How can I make this update in the same command(cmd) or is there any alternative?

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                int burned = 0;
                string s = (comboBox1.SelectedItem).ToString();
                cnn.Open();
                string cmdText = @"SELECT calorificValue 
                       FROM myfitsecret.food 
                       WHERE name=@name;
                       SELECT daily_gained
                       FROM myfitsecret.calorie_tracker 
                       WHERE sportsman_id=@sportsman_id";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
                {
                    // Add both parameters to the same command
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.String).Value = s;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sportsman_id", MySqlDbType.String).Value = Login.userID;
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // get sum from the first result
                        if (reader.Read()) burned += (Convert.ToInt32(reader[0])*int.Parse(textBox1.Text));

                        // if there is a second resultset, go there
                        if (reader.NextResult())
                            if (reader.Read())
                                burned += Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);

                    }

                    cmd.Connection.Close();

                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("update myfitsecret.calorie_tracker set daily_gained=@daily_gained where sportsman_id=@sportsman_id and Date=@Date");
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd2.Connection.Open();
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daily_gained", burned);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", time);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@sportsman_id", MySqlDbType.String).Value = Login.userID;
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the connection to MySqlCommand before trying to open it like this:

```
 cmd.Connection.Close();

 MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("update myfitsecret.calorie_tracker set daily_gained=@daily_gained where sportsman_id=@sportsman_id and Date=@Date",cnn);
 cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd2.Connection.Open();
```

I would also advise wrapping this command in a `using` statement as well.

Comment: I would also advice to use parameters for the query.